# Consecutive terms differ by one letter.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $\{ 1, \cdots, b \}$ be an alphabet and $k$ we denote with
> $W(b,k)$ the set of all words of length $k$ built with that alphabet:
>
> Show that there is a bijection $\varphi : \{ 1, \cdots, |W(b,k)| \}
>  \rightarrow W(b,k)$ such that $\varphi(i)$ and $\varphi(i+1)$ differ
> by exactly one letter ($1 \leq i \leq |W(b,k)| -1 $).

My attempt at a proof was the following:

Domain and codomain are finite and share the same cardinality. Therefore, a bijection $\tilde{\varphi}$ exists. We construct a sequence of $\varphi_i$ of functions in the following manner: $\varphi_1 = \tilde{\varphi}$. Given some $\varphi_i(x)$ such that $\varphi_i(x+1)$ only differs by one letter for $1 \leq x \leq i-1$, we define $\varphi_{i+1}$, by looking through the list for the smallest $l>i$ such that $\varphi_i(i)$ and $\varphi_i(l)$ only differ by one letter. We then define $\varphi_{i+1}(i+1) := \varphi_i(l)$ and $\varphi_{i+1}(l):=\varphi_{i}(i+1)$ and leave $\varphi_{i+1}(x) := \varphi_i(x)$ everywhere else.

Now, the set of $\{i \: |\: \exists \varphi_i \} \subset \{1, \cdots, |W(b,k)| \} < \infty$ is non-empty and must therefore have a maximum $M$. Proving that $M=|W(b,k)|$ is where i fail. I fear i might be missing something extremly obvious, as a contradiction in seems so close, but all my attempts fell short.

Any of the following would be nice to know:

1. Is there is a shorter/more elegant way of doing it, i'd like to know.
2. If my construction works, how to prove it?
3. Any additional Idea/way of going forward is welcome.

Regarding 3., here is (some) of what i've tried and noticed:

- If $M$ is maximal, there is no such $l > M$, this means we have already listed all the words that differ from $\varphi_M(M)$ by one letter.
- In less that $k$ letter changes, you can reach any $\varphi_M(n) \:(n>M)$, from $\varphi_M(M)$, but in order to achieve that, you have to "go back".
- (haven't been able to formalize the thought) Since you always permute and push back the elements that differ, somehow there must be a moment where one of the elements pushed back is the "l" for some $\varphi_i$, therefore the can't be $|W(b,k)| \leq n >M$.
- Since you've listed all the elements that differ from $\varphi_M(M)$ by one letter, you can find a sequence of $(m_t)_{1 \leq t \leq k}$ such that the $t$-th letter of $\varphi_M(n)$ is the $t-th$ letter of $\varphi_M(m_t)$ and $\varphi_M(m_t)$ only differs from $\varphi_M(M)$ by one letter. (which somehow would allow us to conclude that $\varphi_M(n)$ was already listed?).
- $\varphi_j(x) = \varphi_i(x)$ for $j \geq i$ and $x \leq i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about induction on $k$?

Case $k=1$ is evident.

Now let $w_1,w_2,\dots w_{n-1},w_n$ be a sequence of all words in the alphabet that have length $k$ such that two consecutives only differ on exactly one letter.

Then we can form a sortlike sequence for words with length $k+1$ like this:
$$1w_1,1w_2,\dots,1w_{n-1},1w_n,2w_n,2w_{n-1}\cdots2w_2,2w_1,3w_1,3w_2,\dots$$

Comment: This is obvious. Thank you very much!